# Where is the Mail, Calendar and People app storing its data?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

Windows says these apps are 16.4GB combined?! How? Why?
Where are these apps located on your HD?

[image]

I can pretty much say the same about my Windows folder, it keeps getting bigger for no apparent reason and not even CCleaner can prevent any of it...

Comment: How much email do you have? How many contacts? How many events in your calendar?

Comment: It's not the app, it's the data you have stored in it. Unless you tidy up old emails etc,(especially ones with photo/video attachments), empty the trash every so often, it will grow. Having said that, we measure storage in TeraBytes now, 16GB isn't that much these days, not like it would have been in 1992.

Comment: @Tetsujin ...would have been beyond cool in 1992, but could only have happened if you had a time machine.  16GB wasn't able to be stored on a single HDD until 1997 (IBM's 16GP Titan) In '92, the top of the line would have been HP's Kitty Hawk and it only stored 2.1GB

Comment: In 92... might have been later 93, 94, memory fades ... I had a 16GB RAID... I was the coolest kid in the building [even if it was a mish-mash of disparate drives, strung together over SCSI]  ;-) Beside the point, I know, but appreciate the info. [I worked for a VLSI manufacturer, so we got the cool stuff before the public did]

Answer (score 0):

That number includes data that is stored by these applications. It is extremely likely you have the Mail app configured to download your entire Inbox. Under "Settings"->"Accounts"->""->"Download email from", you can set the program to download emails from "Any time", which is what you did.

You can usually address the issue by deleting the largest few emails. Or you can change the setting to only download the emails from the last month.